Create an Application Charge in Shopify issue
I am attempting to create an application charge in Shopify using the admin application API, but I'm encountering an error as:
"It appears that this application is currently owned by a Shop. It must be migrated to the Shopify partners area before it can create charges with the API."
How can I resolve this issue?
I want solution of this.
